# Salesforce Marketng Cloud Personalization - UserETL (Feed Dashboard)

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, interaction-studio

I am attempting to import users into MCP using automation. Upon activation, it takes the file for processing, and approximately 1000 records are encountering an error with the message '**Value must be non-null for the type-detection constructor.**' Since I am using automation, the data extension created for ETL has columns where null values are allowed. However, I am unsure how to resolve this issue.